# Como fazer um campo duma tabela clicável?

Tags: php, javascript, html, table

Estou a fazer um projeto em que quando clico em funcionários abre uma página com a listagem de funcionários como se pode ver na foto. Necessito que o nome de cada funcionário seja clicável, para posteriormente, poder abrir noutra pagina a ficha completa do funcionario com todos os outros campos (morada, data nascimento etc).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eis o que já tentei até agora(código javascript e php/html):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".clickable-row").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).data("href");
});
});

<div class="table-responsive">
                    <?php 
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >0)
                        {
                            echo "<table border='1' class='table table-bordered width='100%' id='dataTable' cellspacing='0'>";
                            echo "<tr><th>Nome Trabalhador</th><th>Função</th><th>ID Trabalhador</th></tr>";

                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result))
                            {                                   
                                echo "<tr class='clickable-row' data-href='http://listar_funcionarios.php?id=" .  $row['id_trabalhador'] . "/'>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['nomeTrabalhador'] ."</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['funcao'] ."</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['id_trabalhador']."</td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            echo "</table>";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo "No results to display!";
                            }
                            mysqli_close($link);
                    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Esse código não funciona? De primeira vista parece estar certo.

Answer (score 1):

Usando jQuery pode-se utilizar o método `window.location.replace($(this).data('href'))`.

Veja um exemplo do funcionamento:

```js
$(".rows").click(
  function(e){
    alert($(this).data('href'));
    window.location.replace($(this).data('href'));
    return false;
  }
)
```

```css
table tr {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableSelector">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Actor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="rows" data-href="http://google.com/1">
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Jon Snow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rows"  data-href="http://google.com/2">
      <th>2</th>
      <td>Sansa Stark</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rows"  data-href="http://google.com/3">
      <th>3</th>
      <td>Arya Stark</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rows"  data-href="http://google.com/4">
      <th>4</th>
      <td>Eddard Stark</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Veja [funcionando no JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cleidimarviana/60szve1n/).

Answer (score 0):

Se vc quer deixar clicável apenas o nome, o mais simples seria inserir a tag a nele.

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><a href='http://listar_funcionarios.php?id=" . $row['id_trabalhador'] . ">" . $row['nomeTrabalhador'] ."</a></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['funcao'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id_trabalhador']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe um plugin do *JQuery* chamado [datatables](https://datatables.net/). É uma ferramenta bem flexível para se trabalhar com tabelas.

O *datatables* já tem uma solução para o seu problema [aqui](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html). Neste link é demonstrado um exemplo contendo os códigos completo. Acredito que a parte mais complexa que terá que desenvolver será a parte da requisição *AJAX*.

Repare na linha `"ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt"` que você terá a opção de passar um arquivo onde o ajax buscará os dados para montar a tabela. Crie uma arquivo `.php` e dentro dele crie a consulta do banco. Traga as informações na mesma estrutura da tabela e aplique um `json_encode` no resultado, por exemplo:

```
$funconarios['data'] = [];    
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  {
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
         array_push($funcionarios['data'],
            [
                'id' => $row['id_trabalhador'],
                'nome' => $row['nomeTrabalhador'],
                'funcao' =>  $row['funcao'],
                /* outros campos */
                'endereco' => $row['funcao'],
                'data_nasc' => $row['funcao'],
                
            ]
        );
     }
     
     echo json_encode($funconarios);
        
}

//Saída do json_enconde
// {
//   "data": [
//         {
//           "id": "1",
//           "name": "Fulano da Silva",
//           "funcao": "Almoxarife",
//           "endereco": "Rua qualquer, 23, Bairo: Tal - Cidade/UF",
//           "data_nasc": "2011/04/22"
//         },
//         {
//           "id": "2",
//           "name": "Cilano da Silva",
//           "funcao": "Secretario",
//           "endereco": "Rua qualquer, 23, Bairo: Tal - Cidade/UF",
//           "data_nasc": "2011/04/22"
//         },
//     ]
// }
```

Outro ponto que você deve prestar atenção é na hora de passar os campos do `data` para o datatbles:

```
{ "data": "name" },
{ "data": "position" },
{ "data": "office" },
{ "data": "salary" }
```

Deve-se estar na mesma ordem e com os mesma definição do array `$funcionarios['data']`.

Caso ainda tenha mais dúvidas é só comentar.